# addToBackstack not working when replacing fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i read the threads about this topic, but it is till not working.

here is my code in the onCreate methode.

```
   if (savedInstanceState==null){
        WeatherFragment weatherFragment = (WeatherFragment) Fragment.instantiate(this, WeatherFragment.class.getName());
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_small, weatherFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

then i replace the fragment.

```
        FrameLayout fl;
        if (findViewById(R.id.container2) != null)
            fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container2);
        else
            fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_small);


        SettingsFragment settingsFragment = (SettingsFragment) Fragment.instantiate(this, SettingsFragment.class.getName());
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_small, settingsFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

now i push the backbutton, and the app dont go back to the first fragment.

any idea why?

Comment: What happens when you press the back button??

Comment: the app dont go back to the previous fragment. ( in my case here the weatherfragment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()!=0)
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
}
```

you need to override the onBackPressed() method

Comment: thank you. it works. i wanted the solution with the methode "addToBackStack". cause it is the suggested one from android developer site.